# Fill blanks $\int_0^1 dx\int_{2x^2}^{x+1}f(y)dy=\int_0^1dy(...)+\int_{1}^2dy(...)$

Tags: integration

How to fill the dots in $$\int_0^1 dx\int_{2x^2}^{x+1}f(y)dy=\int_0^1dy(...)+\int_{1}^2dy(...)?$$

Seems like the area of integration is the following, but I'm able to separate them, the hint says that the first should be $\sqrt{y/2}f(y)$

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second integral when doing $x$ first has $\int_{y-1}^{\sqrt{y/2}}dx$ so the dots are $f(y)(\sqrt{y/2}-y+1)$

The first has a similar form with $0$ as the lower limit and the same upper limit, leading to the hinted value.